# Multiple left to right selection field

Tags: python, django, field

I would like to ask whether there is any field, like the one attached below, available in Django as a single object. If no, then how can we generate such a functionality of moving selected items to the right hand side.

Please guide, I shall be extremly thankful.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could make use of Django's [`FilteredSelectMultiple`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py#L21) widget, as seen in the django-admin when you use [`filter_horizontal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) on a `ManyToManyField`:

[image]

Here's an example of doing it yourself with your own form: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2466/

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in on the client side in JS, something like this: http://www.developergeekresources.com/examples/javascript/javascript-listbox_to_listbox.php

Comment: I believe this is the only way to handle it ... unless you want to reload the page each time you move someone around ...