# In Django how to get this kind of selection box for my app?

Tags: django

In Django admin panel we see a control like shown in image below for user permissions and also selecting groups. I want to add similar control for my application outside of admin. What is this selection control called and where can I learn more about it?

I am clueless about it and in Django documentation I couldn't find anything meaningful.

[image]

Comment: You'll generally need JavaScript for that, I don't know if a server-side framework would generally provide for it. I expect jQuery would have something. A quick search [reveals this](https://github.com/johnvpetersen/jquery-Picker-Plugin).

Comment: thanks halfer. I will try to incorporate this in my application. Have a great day.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919328/multiple-left-to-right-selection-field

Comment: This question may have already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043881/django-admin-manytomanyfield

Comment: Thanks Raj, I will take a look at it and try to integrate it too.  I searched stackoverflow but couldn't find anythign because I didn't even know what to search for. Thanks for sharing.