# How can I create such a form in Django and what is the name of this type of form?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

I'm trying to create a form in Django, part of which is a long list of strings (component names). The user using the form should be able to select one or more components, move them from the left list to the right, and submit these names (in the right list) with the form.

This is also used in the Django administration interface as you can see on my screenshot.

[Django admin interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7xoP.jpg)

Unfortunately, I have no idea what this type of form is called. Therefore it is difficult to find a solution on google if you don't have the right search parameters ...;)

If someone even had a snippet of code to create this form, it would be even better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the answer myself after "adjusting" the search parameters in Google. Before, none of the results matched my question, now I had tried a query "Django forms move several elements from left to right" just for fun. ;) One of the possible solutions was this question here on stackoverflow: "[Multiple left to right selection field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919328/multiple-left-to-right-selection-field)", which then also contained the answer to my question.

If someone else is looking for this type of form, the element is called "FilteredSelectMultiple-Widget with filter_horizontal on a ManyToManyField".